# The gif dont load in this embed,how to fix it?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

in this the gif link doesnt load, I tried adding `.gif` in the end but that too dont work

```
@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.delete(reason="nuke")
    a = await ctx.channel.clone(reason="nuke")
    em = discord.Embed(title = "Nuked")
    em.set_image(url = "https://tenor.com/view/explosion-mushroom-cloud-atomic-bomb-bomb-boom-gif-4464831")
    await a.send(embed = em)
```

Comment: Short answer: discord doesn't allow adding gifs in embeds

Comment: but it works with some different gif links tho

Comment: That's weird, maybe they work since the new update, they didn't a couple of months ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenor, seemingly, does not allow linking directly to the `.gif` file, even when using "Open image in new tab" in a desktop browser. It instead opens Tenor's UI with a small viewer.

Look for direct links to images that you wish to send. GIF providers often do not provide direct links.

You can either try to use the [Tenor API](https://tenor.com/gifapi) to get the direct link, or download the GIF file and send it directly. You could also download the GIF and re-upload it onto another image host which allows sending and directly linking to GIFs.

Note that some hosts like [Imgur](https://imgur.com/) convert GIF files into short, looping videos in MP4 format. Although, for Imgur specifically, you can get the direct link by right-clicking, selecting "Open video in new tab", and replacing the `.mp4` suffix with `.gif`.